# How to get MathJax to typeset again? MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]); doesn't seem to work.

Tags: html, ajax, mathjax

I am having trouble with MathJax. It is not rendering content after the Ajax call. I tried calling

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
```

But it seems to be not working. What am I doing wrong? 
Also, if I try to include the non-deprecated src url to mathjax given on their website, mathjax doesn't work completely for me.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>MathJax AsciiMath Test Page</title>
        <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
          MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
                               displayMath: [['\\[','\\]'], ['$$','$$']]}});
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
          src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
        </script>
        <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>

        <button type="button">Math</button>
        <div class='math'>
          <p>\[x(n+1)=x(n)+dt*v(n)\]</p>
        </div>

        <script>
          $(function(){
            $('button').on('click', function(){
              console.log('click');
              var myCustomEvent = new Event('ReloadMath');
              document.dispatchEvent(myCustomEvent);
            });
            $.get('/text', function(text){
               $('.math').append("<p>Hi</p>");
               $('.math').append("<p>\[x(n+1)=x(n)+dt*v(n)\]</p>");
               MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
            });
          });

          document.addEventListener('ReloadMath', function () {
            console.log('reload math');
            MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
          });
        </script>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I got it, the jquery was getting to it before the Ajax and removing that /[ /] tags. I just replaced the /[ by $ $ and everything works.

Comment: It's actually due to JavaScript requiring backslashes to be escaped in strings, e.g. `\\[...\\[`.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash (`\`) is an escape character in JavaScript and when Javascript finds a backslash in a String, it will try to escape the character after it. To show a backslash in a String, you will need to escape it with a preceding backslash, meaning that you will need two backslashes to display one backslash i.e. `\\`.

You will need to change

```
$('.math').append("<p>\[x(n+1)=x(n)+dt*v(n)\]</p>");
```

To

```
$('.math').append("<p>\\[x(n+1)=x(n)+dt*v(n)\\]</p>");
```